# How to disable redshift (service) on startup

Tags: xubuntu, services, redshift

I have redshift installed on a XUbuntu 21.04. Apparently it's a service
`systemd[4048]: redshift.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'`
and it runs at startup.

**I'd like to disable redshift on startup**, but I can't find where and in which format it's started:

```
> systemctl stop redshift
> Failed to stop redshift.service: Unit redshift.service not loaded.
```

`systemctl list-units --type=service`
Doesn't list it

The only thing that worked so far was a couple of
`sudo killall redshift` calls right after booting

Answer (score 2):

According to [RedShift](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/amd64/redshift/filelist) [filelists](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/all/redshift-gtk/filelist) it has systemd service for users.
To disable it use command below:

```
systemctl --user mask redshift.service redshift-gtk.service
```

and then reboot.

Also it is known that redshift service is [broken](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/redshift/+bug/1910270) [at least](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-hirsute-hippo-final-release/) on Ubuntu MATE 21.04, so really we can prevent its start on LightDM startup by executing the following commands for manual masking:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/lightdm/.config/systemd/user
sudo ln -sf /dev/null /var/lib/lightdm/.config/systemd/user/redshift.service  
sudo ln -sf /dev/null /var/lib/lightdm/.config/systemd/user/redshift-gtk.service
sudo chown -R lightdm: /var/lib/lightdm/.config
```

Note: Xubuntu also uses LightDM, so the above will work for it too.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Service kept starting.

Comment: Use `mask` instead of `disable`.

Comment: Removing is no option, as I'm actually using it - just not as service.

Comment: This worked for me using redshift 1.12 on Pop OS 21.04

Answer (score 1):

@N0rbert's solution did not work for me, although it was a pointer in the right direction.

I found user services in `/usr/lib/systemd/user` and changed `redshift.service` to `redshift.service.disabled`. That stopped running on boot.